# Firebase data connection not working in react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I new to react native and creating a database connection with firebase.
I'm getting an error while calling firebase function. 
I'm getting an error for `db.database`. See below.

[image]

And here's my code. Please help me if anyone has an idea why I'm getting this error.

```
getItem(itemsRef) {
  this.setState({
    db.database().ref('/users/').orderByChild('userId').on('value', snapshot => {
      // itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {
      let items = [];
      snap.forEach((child) => {
        items.push({
          title: child.val().title,
          _key: child.key
        })
      })
      itemDataSource: this.state.itemDataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: What is your expectation with `this.setState({ /*functioncall*/ });`? Shouldn't it be inside the callback?

Comment: @Caramiriel, thank you. it solved the problem. i was following this tutorial [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIu0MNirS1M] and missed this part where he changes setState